# Second order differential equation $y'' + y = x\cos{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve it using the method of undetermined coefficients or operator method. In undetermined coefficients I used $y = Ax^2 \cos x + Bx^2 \sin x$ as a particular solution but it is not helping. What particular solution I should try?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the method correctly. If the right side already has a polynomial factor in front of the exponential or trigonometric term, then the undetermined coefficients need to be for a full polynomial of the same degree. Additionally, you get a monomial factor for the multiplicity of the characteristic root, if it is the same as in the exponential. Thus
$$
y_p(x)=x(A_0+A_1x)\cos x+x(B_0+B_1x)\sin x.
$$
You could try to argue by symmetry that certain of these coefficients ($A_1,\,B_0$ possibly?) have to be automatically zero.

Answer (score 0):

Set $y_p=a x \cos (x)+b x^2 \sin (x)$

You'll get $a=b=1/4$ and you are done.

Comment: How did u get that particular solution?

Comment: @Xyz  trial and error

Answer (score 0):

$$y'' + y = x\cos{x}$$
Rewrite it as:
$$y'' + y = x\Re {e^{ix}}$$
For less calculations, you can also  try the complex exponential as a guess:
$$y_p=x(Ax+B)e^{ix}$$